# Python Pandas - Find missing rows, and then duplicate another row with modifications

Tags: python, pandas

Have a data source where each row is uniquely defined by two columns. However, some rows are missing, which need to be inserted with some information from the dataframe.

So with the table below, we are missing when A=2, and B=20.

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | A |
| 2 | 10 | B |
| 3 | 10 | C |
| 1 | 20 | D |
| 3 | 20 | E |

I have managed to list the missing data by using looping over the df using the .any command. That outputs that A=2, B=20 is missing. However, I can't seem to duplicate the row above (A=1, B=20) and modify column C.

My issue is that using .any, I know what is missing, but I can't locate (A=1, B=20) to duplicate the row.

Also might be going about the whole thing is a suboptimal manner - so open to any suggestions!

Comment: kindly post your expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are after - You can use the [complete](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.complete.html#janitor.complete) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/index.html) to expose the missing combinations; at the moment you have to install the latest development version from [github](https://github.com/ericmjl/pyjanitor):

```
# install latest dev version
# pip install git+https://github.com/ericmjl/pyjanitor.git

import janitor
df.complete(["A", "B"])

    A   B   C
0   1   10  A
1   1   20  D
2   2   10  B
3   2   20  NaN
4   3   10  C
5   3   20  E
```

Using Pandas' only, we can create [unique](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.unique.html) values for columns 'A' and 'B", build a new [MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html), then [reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) the dataframe:

```
new_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.A.unique(), df.B.unique()], 
                                        names=["A", "B"])
new_index

MultiIndex([(1, 10),
            (1, 20),
            (2, 10),
            (2, 20),
            (3, 10),
            (3, 20)],
           names=['A', 'B'])
```

Now, [set index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.set_index), [reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) and [reset index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.reset_index):

```
df.set_index(["A", "B"]).reindex(new_index).reset_index()

    A   B   C
0   1   10  A
1   1   20  D
2   2   10  B
3   2   20  NaN
4   3   10  C
5   3   20  E
```

You can also fill the null value:

```
 df.set_index(["A", "B"]).reindex(new_index, fill_value=0).reset_index()
```

The [complete](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.complete.html#janitor.complete) function requires that you pass a dictionary (or you could just use [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) instead and not worry about a dictionary):

```
df.complete(["A", "B"], fill_value={"C": 0}) # or df.complete(["A", "B"]).fillna(0)

    A   B   C
0   1   10  A
1   1   20  D
2   2   10  B
3   2   20  0
4   3   10  C
5   3   20  E
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Using only Panda's it correctly extracts the MultiIndex in question, when using the line set_index, it does not appear to change the the output (still get  5 rows not the 6). Will download pyjanitor..

Comment: How many rows do you get for the multiindex? 6 rows? Same output as in the answer provided? The number of rows for A and B in the dataframe you shared is 5, so when you set the index and reindex you should have 6 rows which introduces the nan. I think you should have a closer look.

Comment: Great - Got that now working under both pyjanitor and the pandas method. How do I now go about replacing the NaN in Col C. Ideally I would take the value "D" (For A=1, B=20, C is "D"). Thanks!

Comment: I edited my answer showing how to replace values