# Python - add a timestamp column if meet condition in csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime

I have a csv file that look like this:

```
       MAC
bc:95:50:0a:82:80
bc:95:50:0a:82:80
bc:95:50:0a:82:80
bc:95:50:0a:82:80

bc:95:50:0a:85:60
bc:95:50:0a:85:60
bc:95:50:0a:85:60
bc:95:50:0a:85:60
bc:95:50:0a:85:60

bc:95:50:9e:58:40
bc:95:50:9e:58:40
bc:95:50:9e:58:40
bc:95:50:9e:58:40
bc:95:50:9e:58:40
```

There are 3 MAC addresses in my csv file and I want to add a 5 mins timestamp for each MAC address like this:

```
        MAC             Time
bc:95:50:0a:82:80   2020-11-30 7:05
bc:95:50:0a:82:80   2020-11-30 7:10
bc:95:50:0a:82:80   2020-11-30 7:15
bc:95:50:0a:82:80   2020-11-30 7:20

bc:95:50:0a:85:60   2020-11-30 7:05
bc:95:50:0a:85:60   2020-11-30 7:10
bc:95:50:0a:85:60   2020-11-30 7:15
bc:95:50:0a:85:60   2020-11-30 7:20
bc:95:50:0a:85:60   2020-11-30 7:25

bc:95:50:9e:58:40   2020-11-30 7:05
bc:95:50:9e:58:40   2020-11-30 7:10
bc:95:50:9e:58:40   2020-11-30 7:15
bc:95:50:9e:58:40   2020-11-30 7:20
```

Right now I can only generate the timestamp:

```
dt = datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 30, 7, 5, 0)
end = datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 30, 23, 59, 59)
step = datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)

result = []
while dt < end:
    result.append(dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    dt += step
wtr = csv.writer(open ('out.csv', 'w'), delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
for x in result:
    wtr.writerow ([x])
```

But I don't know how to add these timestamps to the MAC column.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expand dataframe for each date | Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66039611/expand-dataframe-for-each-date-pandas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Henry, I have created the data frame below, but you can read from CSV

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'MAC': {0: 'bc:95:50:0a:82:80',
  1: 'bc:95:50:0a:82:80',
  2: 'bc:95:50:0a:82:80',
  3: 'bc:95:50:0a:82:80',
  4: 'bc:95:50:0a:85:60',
  5: 'bc:95:50:0a:85:60',
  6: 'bc:95:50:0a:85:60',
  7: 'bc:95:50:0a:85:60',
  8: 'bc:95:50:0a:85:60',
  9: 'bc:95:50:9e:58:40',
  10: 'bc:95:50:9e:58:40',
  11: 'bc:95:50:9e:58:40',
  12: 'bc:95:50:9e:58:40',
  13: 'bc:95:50:9e:58:40'}})

import datetime
import csv
import numpy as np

dt = datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 30, 7, 5, 0)
step = datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
  
df['cumct'] = df.groupby('MAC').cumcount()+1
df['date'] = df['cumct'] * step + dt
df = df.drop(columns='cumct')
df.to_csv('out.csv', index=False)
```

The out.csv looks like this -

```
MAC,date
bc:95:50:0a:82:80,2020-11-30 07:10:00
bc:95:50:0a:82:80,2020-11-30 07:15:00
bc:95:50:0a:82:80,2020-11-30 07:20:00
bc:95:50:0a:82:80,2020-11-30 07:25:00
bc:95:50:0a:85:60,2020-11-30 07:10:00
bc:95:50:0a:85:60,2020-11-30 07:15:00
bc:95:50:0a:85:60,2020-11-30 07:20:00
bc:95:50:0a:85:60,2020-11-30 07:25:00
bc:95:50:0a:85:60,2020-11-30 07:30:00
bc:95:50:9e:58:40,2020-11-30 07:10:00
bc:95:50:9e:58:40,2020-11-30 07:15:00
bc:95:50:9e:58:40,2020-11-30 07:20:00
bc:95:50:9e:58:40,2020-11-30 07:25:00
bc:95:50:9e:58:40,2020-11-30 07:30:00
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to add a time column to your csv file. The time column is to hold timestamps with a five minute interval.

I recommend using pandas when dealing with csv files, because pandas dataframes are so easy to manipulate. See the below code and let me know if it solves your problem.

```
import pandas as pd

csv_file_path = "something.csv"
new_csv_file_path = "something_wtimestamp.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file_path)
timestamp_index = pd.date_range(
    start=pd.Timestamp(2020, 11, 30, 7, 5, 0), 
    end=pd.Timestamp(2020, 11, 30, 23, 59, 59), 
    freq='5T') #T = minute
timestamp_col = pd.Series(timestamp_index)
df["Time"] = timestamp_col
df.to_csv(new_csv_file_path)
```

If your start and end are configured to exactly match the length of your MAC column, you can skip converting the index to a Series. As a series, the timestamp will only populate the current rows (i.e. get cut off). This saves you fussing over calculating 5 minutes * length of dataframe.